# Can some one explain me or give me the link how the gesture detector works?

Tags: android, gesture, toast

Can some one explain me or give me the link how the gesture detector works?i have been looking for the proper documentation or explanation all over the internet but all i get is the source code.....
i trying to implement gestures in my app so i copy pasted the code available on the net...but it disables the scroll and other functionalists so i thought why not to get the proper understanding of the code instead of just copy pasting it...so please any help will be greatly appreciated...please provide me with links.

by the way this is my code

```
package i.rock.fb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater blowup=getMenuInflater();
         blowup.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new our());
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");




    /*@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

 webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });}
    final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                boolean result = false;WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {

                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {

                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                        }
                    } 

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;

        }

     }




     public void onSwipeRight() {WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
         webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
         webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    */}}
```

if you can correct it ,it would be helpful,but still i would recommend that you tell give me the link so that i can read more about it..
there is another class which i have made so that the links open up in the same app and not in the inbuilt web apps..

package i.rock.fb;

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class our extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best tutorial I have encountered for using GestureDetector. Try it, it will amaze you as to what all these Gestures can achieve.

[Mobile Tuts Plus... the link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't forget to call super.onTouchEvent :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

You'll need to provide more details about your code and what you intend to do.